# Is there a more up-to-date / wider-scope version of the 'Compendium of NP Optimization Problems'

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, optimization, np

When I was studying Comp Sci, we had [Garey & Johnson](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0716710455) as a course textbook, with a large collection of NP-Complete problems. But by that time you could also have a look at the [Compendium of NP Optimization Problems](http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~diam/ro/online/viggo_wwwcompendium/wwwcompendium.html), online.

However, it seems the 'Compendium' site has not seen any updates in several years. Is that indeed the case? Is there a more up-to-date compendium (perhaps in print) which accounts for further research and contains more problems in more domains?

Answer (score 5):

I know of no compendium that is completely satisfactory in any regard. It seems to be too much of a thankless task maintaining these things, thus I suspect that broad answer to your question is, unfortunately, no.

However, there are several resources which, together, are at least a good start for any search.

In this case, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NP-complete_problems) is a fairly decent resource (I guess the contribution model helps overcome some of the problems with a single-curator approach, but you lose the consistency).

If you're interested in Parameterized Complexity, Marco Cesati began a [compendium of problems](http://cesati.sprg.uniroma2.it/research/compendium/), but like Kann, has (understandably) not kept up with the updates. There's also an [online compendium](http://www.compendium-fpt.com/), but it is less comprehensive.

A similar question was also asked on [cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5855/catalog-of-np-complete-problems-more-up-to-date-than-gareyjohnson), attracting a couple of answers, one that caught my eye was the [Encyclopedia of Algorithms](http://www.springer.com/computer/theoretical+computer+science/book/978-0-387-30770-1). I cannot personally vouch for it, but it at least looks useful, or at least useful enough to convince a university library to buy.